# If Entry is related to Category-A, then print xyz

Tags: categories, relations

I have succussfully been able to list entries within the 'brandx' category slug, but I can't figure out a way to print specific content **only if** the current 'product' listing is related to the 'brandx' category.

I have tried quite a few things and have come up empty, so I feel like I'm either missing something basic, or there's a trick I can't find in the docs or here.

```
{% paginate craft.entries.section('shopDetails').level(1).limit(24) as postsOnPage %} 
      {% for product in postsOnPage %}
           …
            <h5>
              {% set cat = craft.categories.slug('brandx').first() %}
              {% set catGroup = craft.entries.relatedTo( cat ) %}
              {% if product {# is within the catGroup #}  %}
              Brand X
              {% endif %}
              {{ product.title }}
            </h5>
{% endpaginate %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is this in the `product` for Loop

```
{% if product.category.first.slug == 'brandx' %}
    Brand X
{% endif %}
```

Or Shorthand

```
{{ product.category.first.slug == 'brandx' ? 'Brand X' }}
```

Not tested but thats the gist of it.

--Edited

Comment: Yep works with a couple of formatting edits. This solution is particularly annoying since my first gut was to just pull from the category field, but I didn't include the 'first'. I'm still unclear when 'first' is needed (time to research).

Comment: `first` is needed whenever the default returns an array (or an array-like object), you know there is only one, or you only want the first one. I.e. an assets, category, entries, or users field for example that you have set a limit of 1.

Comment: This is nice and tidy, but will not work if you have set multiple categories before `brandx`.

I have used:

    {% set isBrandx = false %}
    {% for item in product.category %}
        {% if product.slug == 'brandx' %}
            {% set isBrandx = true %}
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}

I can then test against `isBrandx` wherever I want. Open to suggestions, however!